# Ruby: Accessing class instance variables from one class in another class's class method

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, attr-accessor

I am working on a ruby program and have run into the following problem.

I have two classes AClass and BClass as follows:

```
class AClass
  attr_accessor :avar
  def initialize(input)
    @avar = input
  end
end

class BClass
  def BClass.build(aclass)
    bvalue = aclass.avar
    ....
  end
end
```

When i run:

```
aclass = AClass.new           
puts aclass.avar              
bclass = BClass.build(aclass)
```

The first two lines work fine.  aclass is intialized and avar is put out to the screen, but the third line creates an error. I seems that the BClass build method can not access the AClass instance variable.    What do I need to do to make this work.  I thought the attr_accessor would enable me to access the AClass instance variables.  Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: you have 2 different variables there avar and avar1.  Also the first line `class AClass(input)` is not ruby...

Comment: Augusto, Sorry for the typo.  Both variables are supposed to be avar. I've made the correction. Thanks.

Comment: but still is input at the right place?

Comment: Zimbabao - you're right. input was in the wrong place.  Thanks.

Comment: For future reference, an object which has a class of `AClass` would usually be called `a_class`, not `aclass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a new type of initializer for BClass, you can do the following:

```
class AClass
  attr_accessor :avar

  def initialize(input)
    @avar = input
  end
end

class BClass
  attr_accessor :bvalue

  def self.build(aclass)
    bclass = self.new
    bclass.bvalue = aclass.avar
    bclass
  end
end

aclass = AClass.new 'ruby'
bclass = BClass.build aclass
```

This will set bclass.bvalue = aclass.avar = 'ruby'.

Answer (score 0):

Mutu, you need to learn the basics of ruby... what you have there is not even valid ruby code.

try running this.

```
class AClass
  attr_accessor :avar

  def initialize(input)
    @avar = input
  end
end

class BClass
  attr_reader :bvalue

  def initialize(aclass)
    @bvalue = aclass.avar
  end
end
```

in irb

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :077 > a = AClass.new('ruby')
 => #<AClass:0x00000100997298 @avar="ruby"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :078 > b = BClass.new(a)
 => #<BClass:0x000001009921d0 @bvalue="ruby"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :079 > b.bvalue
 => "ruby" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :080 > a.avar
 => "ruby"
```

Comment: I was trying to communicate the jist of my problem without writing out all of my code, but perhaps I've not provided enough information.  Let me take another crack at it. Thanks again.